# Is this a valid approach to cross site request anti forgery?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am implementing a "sign in with Google plus".

Google's instructions say I must send an anti forgery token when the user requests my signin HTML page.

My understanding is that I include my anti forgery token in the HTML of my signin page, the user clicks the "sign in to Google plus" button, and if the signin is successful, a code is returned by Google to my signin page.  My signin page must then return this code back to my server via an ajax POST request.

I understand that in addition to returning the code that Google gave me, I must also send back my own anti forgery token. I then look up this token to make sure it is one that I previously sent.

So here is my context and question.

Context:

I do not wish to store tokens at the back end, I want my login page to be stateless. My understanding is that the solution to this is to make my anti forgery token a key and random number which my server signs. When I get it back, I check to make sure the key is the same as what was sent.

My question is:

Is this approach valid? Surely an attacker could simply ask for my login page, grab the anti forgery token out of it, and send it back along with the request that they have somehow hijacked.
Or am I somehow meant to bind my server generated anti forgery token specifically to the particular user request, for example round tripping my anti forgery token through the Google plus API and then reading the token back at the server end when I exchange it?

Man my mind is bending. I'm not sure if I understand this properly.

Comment: Yes, you're supposed to have a token for each request you're validating.  Otherwise, like you said, it's pretty pointless.

Comment: Pointless really?  How come Google (and lots of other sources on the web) seem to make such a big deal of the anti forgery token thing?

Comment: It's meant to prevent CSRF attacks.

Comment: search for 'double submit cookie'... also, check http://security.stackexchange.com